# Core Data - Possible to model an OR relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Let's say I have an entity called `EntityA`. EntityA has a relationship to `EntityB` and `EntityC`. Neither of EntityB and EntityC are mandatory relationships but one of them has to be chosen.

Is it possible to model this in Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If EntityB and EntityC had a common super-class, you could have a required relationship of that type.

That said, I have heard it said you should stay away from class hierarchies in Core Data.

YMMV

Comment: Useful indeed. So this is the only way of achieving this?

Comment: You can also have two relations on EntityA and override `validateForUpdate:` and `validateForInsert:` where you can make own relation check.

Answer (score 0):

You can have any kind of custom constraint on you model object. I assume that's what you're asking about?

Check the **Managed Object Validation** document inside the Core Data documentation. What you're looking for is *Inter-Property validation*. You can implement custom `-validateFor…` methods for update, insertion, and deletion. In your case you'd check that either the relationship to entity B or the relationship to entity C is set.

Having a common super-entity messes with the way data of these entities is stored to disk — that's probably not what you want.

Comment: In what way does it "mess" how the data of those entities are stored on disk?